# Auto select a tab on HTML button click using tab name instead of tab id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

How to auto select a tab on HTML button click by using the title of the tab instead of it's index. 
By using tab index it can be done like this:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active", index_of_tab );
```

For details refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033490/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-no-such-method-select-for-tabs-widget-instanc)

Is there any way to get tab id from tab title so that I can use the above code? Or is there any way to auto select a tab using tab name?

Comment: what do you mean by tab name ? name attribute or tab title ?

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity, its for tab title.

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the tab's id containing that title, after that you'll get the id from that id (using substring) and finally select the tab by index (using id number -1 ).

I've created a function to perform these action `fselectTabByTitle(title)`

Bellow you can find a complete example :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();


  $(".btn").on("click", function() {
    selectTabByTitle($(this).data("title"))
  })

});

function selectTabByTitle(title) {
  var tab = $("#tabs ul>li a:contains(" + title + ")");
  if (tab[0]) {
    var tabid = tab[0].id;
    var tabIndex = tabid.substr(tabid.length - 1);
    $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active', tabIndex - 1);
  }
}
```

```css
#tabs {
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Content for Tab 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Content for Tab 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Content for Tab 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="tabid"></div>
<button class="btn" data-title="Tab 1">
select Tab1
</button>
<button class="btn" data-title="Tab 2">
select Tab2
</button>
<button class="btn" data-title="Tab 3">
select Tab3
</button>
```

Comment: PLease up and mark the answer as resolved if  this last help you , may be this help other person !

Answer (score 1):

To do this you have to get index of tab by using tab name that can be done as shown below,

```
var index = $('#tabs a[href="#your-tab"]').parent().index();
```

In above code a[#your-tab] is link given to your tab,After getting index you can do,

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active", index );
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: how to pass variable's name in place of "#your-tab"?
`var index = $('.selector a[href="#"'+name_of_tab+']').parent().index();`
This i tried, but getting error saying `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .selector a[href="#"name_of_tab]`

Comment: You can do like this,var index=$('#tabs a[href]="'+variable+'"]').blabla();